# Código para receber arquivo através de POST

Tags: c#, visual-basic-6, asp.net-web-api

Estou fazendo uma webAPI para receber arquivos via post.

O cliente vai enviar via vb clássico com o seguinte código:

```
Set content = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
content.Open "POST", url, False
content.setRequestHeader "TOKEN", token    
content.Send (ConteudoXML)
STR=content.readystate 
ST=content.status
ST_TXT=content.statusText
ws  = content.responseText
Response.write "<br>Status Read:" & STR & "<br>Status:" & ST    & "<br>Status TXT:" & ST_TXT   & "<br>Resposta:" & ws
Set content = Nothing
```

Ele está usando ASP 1.0, então o código de envio não pode ser alterado.

O código de recebimento que estou utilizando é

```
if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data")) {
throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
}

var sPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/certificados/");

var re = Request;
var headers = re.Headers;

MultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(sPath);

var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
```

O problema é que o código de recebimento não está reconhecendo o arquivo e está sempre retornando HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType.

Vou precisar receber arquivo que esteja em outro formato(.pfx) também.